# Случайный выбор одной из 4-х функций JS

Tags: javascript, функции

Есть код, в нем описаны 4 типа движения вверх, вниз, влево, вправо (это 4 отдельные ф-и). Помогите написать функцию, которая будет выбирать случайную из них и вызывать её

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function up() {
  console.log("Moving Up...");
}

function down() {
  console.log("Moving Down...");
}

function left() {
  console.log("Moving Left...");
}

function right() {
  console.log("Moving Right...");
}

let funcs = [up, down, left, right];
funcs[Math.random() * 4 | 0]();
```

2 последние строчки. Помещаем интересующие 4 функции в массив, затем обращаемся к случайному элементу массива (`Math.random() * 4 | 0` означает случайное целое число от 0 до 3 включительно) и вызываем полученную функцию при помощи круглых скобок.

И да, если Вам нужна именно функция, то вот

```js
function up() {
  console.log("Moving Up...");
}

function down() {
  console.log("Moving Down...");
}

function left() {
  console.log("Moving Left...");
}

function right() {
  console.log("Moving Right...");
}

// просто обборачиваем функцией moveSomewhere, ничего особенного
function moveSomewhere() {
  return [up, down, left, right][Math.random() * 4 | 0]();
}

moveSomewhere();
```

В принципе, если есть желание/необходимость, можно объединить все это в одну строку (как я и поступил в примере выше).

Если у Вас всего 4 функции движения (вверх, вниз, влево и вправо), то следующий более абстрактный подход может быть и излишен, но тем не менее иногда лучше продумать все наперед. А мало ли потом еще перемещения по диагоналям добавить решите?

```js
function up() {
  console.log("Moving Up...");
}

function down() {
  console.log("Moving Down...");
}

function left() {
  console.log("Moving Left...");
}

function right() {
  console.log("Moving Right...");
}

function invokeRandomFunc() {
  return arguments[Math.random() * arguments.length | 0]();
}

invokeRandomFunc(up, down, left, right);
```

Answer (score 2):

Передавайте **randomFunc** функции (без круглых скобок) в качестве аргументов.

```
function randomFunc(...funcs) {
        // Функция генератор случайных чисел
        const getRandomInt = (min, max) => {
            min = Math.ceil(min);
            max = Math.floor(max);
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        }
        // Генерируем случайное число из количества функций
        const indexFunc = getRandomInt(0, funcs.length-1);
        // Вызываем функцию
        funcs[indexFunc]();
    }
```

Пример

```
randomFunc(up, down, left, right);
```